# Grammar using the word 'at' , 'in'

Tags: prepositions

Yesterday afternoon I arrived Delhi.
So if I want to Inform my friends which word should I use

I am At Delhi or I am in delhi

Comment: Use 'in' because it's broader and not a 'closed' place. So, you are 'in' city but 'at' town-hall!

Answer (score 2):

When speaking about position, *in* is generally used for large places such as countries or cities, while *at* is used for smaller places.

Since Delhi is a city, you need to use *in*. Using *at* makes your sentence sound off.

> - I arrived **in** Delhi.
> - I am currently **in** India.
> - I'm **in** Asia.

But:

> - I am **at** the bank.
> - I'm **at** Delhi city center.

Comment: .. Thanks a lot one more question pls.. How to differentiate betweenwhether it is a  small places and large places. For example.. I arrived at Vapi is correct or I am in Vapi is correct

Comment: The border between *in* and *at* can be quite vague. For small villages you can start considering to use *at* instead of *in*, so I guess that is where one could draw the line.

Comment: Trains were cancelled due to heavy rains.. I want to ask my friend to let me know if the train service will start..how do I form proper sentance

Comment: Please make a new question post for questions that are not related to this one.